# Neo4j: How to open an existing database in neo4j using java api?

Tags: java, neo4j

How to use the existing database in neo4j using java api? I already created a neo4j database and wanted to use it for several queries. However, when I opened the existing database I created and did some query, it returned nothing. The fragment of code I am using is as follows:

```
private static final String DB_PATH = "c:/Users/Reed/workspace/test/target1/ttldb";
GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );


ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( db );

ExecutionResult result;

try ( Transaction tx = db.beginTx(); )
{

    result = engine.execute( "match (n) return n" );

    Iterator<Node> n_column = result.columnAs( "n" );
    for ( Node node : IteratorUtil.asIterable( n_column ) )
    {

        nodeResult = node + ": " + node.getProperty( "name" );

        System.out.println(nodeResult);
    }
    tx.success();

}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your variable `nodeResult` isn't declared. Are you really sure that your database contains data? How did you create the data? Did you commit after your import?

Comment: By default, the neo4j database will not have any data. You should make sure that when you do perform writes in your database you are committing them, and that you are closing the DB properly(using a shutdown hook to ensure that the data is flushed properly).

Comment: if your path is the good one (the db folder you want to get) everything should work fine. The only thing missing is a `finally{tx.close()}` block at the end of your try clause.

Comment: You should consider where your neo4j database is coming from also. If the database you are reading is at a wildly different version from your client, you may run into trouble. The neo4j site is pretty clear on what database versions can be read by what clients.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Neo4j in embedded mode i.e. it runs within the same JVM as your application, you can access it using:

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DBPATH)
```

where DBPATH is the path to the database you created using Webadmin. You can find that path in your neo4j install directory/conf/neo4j-server.properties (The property name is org.neo4j.server.database.location)

Once you have instantiated your graphDb, you can [Execute Cypher queries from Java](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/tutorials-java-embedded/#tutorials-cypher-java)

If you are not using Neo4j in embedded mode and want to connect to the existing server running on port 7474, you can use the java rest binding: https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding/